# Find dataframe in list containing specific rowname in R

Tags: r, list, row, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes.  Is there a way of finding the index of the dataframe which contains a specific rowname?

For example, say I had

```
mylist<-list(
          data.frame(c(1,1),c(1,1),row.names = c('row1','row2')),
          data.frame(c(1,1),c(1,1),row.names = c('row3','row4'))
             )
```

And I wanted to find where `row3` was, the query would return 2 as it is in the second dataframe in my list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x)"row3" %in% rownames(x))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Or a variation on the same theme, which returns `NA` if the rowname can't be found, and the row number if it can:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x)match("row3", rownames(x)))
[1] NA  1
```

Comment: Thanks, and to get the number of the dataframe  in the list I did     which(sapply(mylist, function(x)"row3" %in% rownames(x)))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
> lapply(lapply(mylist,rownames),function(x){any(grepl('row3',x))})
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

#> seq_along(mylist)[sapply(lapply(mylist,rownames),function(x){any(grepl('row3',x))})]
#[1] 2
#>
```

Comment: There is no need for iterating over the rownames if you use `%in%`, see Andrie's answer.